# Procesar por lotes una colección de entidades en OData

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, odata

En mi cliente AngularJS mando este POST

```
...
entidades = [];
entidades = procesaEntidades();

$http.post('http://blabla/entidades',JSON.stringify(entidades))
.then(function(){alert('ok')},function(err){alert('error');});
```

En mi servidor Odata tengo este controller, el cual no me es posible alcanzar:

```
public class EntidadesController : ODataController
    {
       public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(IEnumerable<Entidad> entidades)
         {

            // TODO: Add create logic here.
            var x = entidades;

            //ACTUALIZA BASE DE DATOS BLA BLA BLA
            ...
```

El problema es que no puedo alcanzar al controller y el cliente me arroja el siguiente error:

```
'ODataFeedDeserializer' does not support Read
```

Investigando un poco, resulta que Odata no puede recibir colecciones (?)

Lo demas esta correcto por que si mando una sola entidad y cambio la definicion del controller, recibo la entidad correctamente:

Cliente

```
 $http.post('http://blabla/entidades',JSON.stringify(entidades[0]))
.then(function(){alert('ok')},function(err){'error'});
```

Servidor

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Entidad entidad)
 {
    //entidad recibida correctamente
```

**Por que no puedo POST(ear) colecciones desde AngularJS a Odata?**

**Como puedo POST(ear) colecciones desde AngularJS a Odata?**

**EDICIÓN:**

Versiones del sofware

- "Microsoft.AspNet.OData" version="5.8.0" targetFramework="net451"
- "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451"
- "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.3.1" targetFramework="net451"
- AngularJS 1.5.0

Comment: podrías especificar las versiones que estas usando de: OData, AngularJS y C# ?

Comment: @fredyfx Listo.

Comment: porque tiene que realizar el JSON.stringify() de la entidad para enviarla? que pasa si la asignas directo Ademas aconsejaria que visualizas si recibes un error desde http, cuando capturas el error desde $http deberias analizarlo o en su defecto usar el Developer tools del browser (al cual accedes con F12) para ver que respuesta brinda

Comment: Si uso las herramientas de desarrollo del explorador, sin JSON.stringify me marca mas errores, ya me di cuenta que tienes que usar $batch, lo cual le añade mas lineas de codigo, voy a preparar una respuesta, por lo pronto estoy usando webApi para hacer las inserciones.

Comment: lograste resolver el problema?

Comment: Como tenia que entregar el programa mejor use WebAPI, pero si se puede usando $batch, en estos dias voy a hacer la prueba y voy a publicar una respuesta

Comment: hey @Tuco, cómo te fue? todo bien?

Answer (score 2):

OData permite realizar operaciones sobre varias entidades con una sola petición web usando la funcionalidad de [procesado por lotes](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/batch-processing/)

A grandes rasgos, esta funcionalidad consiste en juntar cada una de las peticiones que se enviarían individualmente en una única petición de tipo [multipart](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html).

- Cada uno de los bloques que componen esta petición se identifican de forma única para posteriormente poder extraer el resultado que le corresponde.
- La construcción de estas peticiones tiene cierta complejidad porque hay que trabajar a bajo nivel con los encabezados y contenido de la petición

Por suerte existe un proyecto en GitHub llamado [angular-http-batcher](https://github.com/jonsamwell/angular-http-batcher) que hace este trabajo de forma trasparente convirtiendo varias peticiones web realizadas con el servicio [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) en una sola petición batch.

Usando el código de ejemplo que se incluye en el proyecto para realizar una petición múltiple:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/products').then(function (data) {
    console.log('success on batch call No.0 - ' + data.data);
}, function (err) {
    console.log('error on batch call No.0 - ' + err);
});

$http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/products/2').then(function (data) {
    console.log('success on batch call No.1 - ' + data.data);
}, function (err) {
    console.log('error on batch call No.1 - ' + err);
});

$http.put('http://localhost:8080/api/products', {
    Name: 'Product X',
    StockQuantity: 300
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log('success on batch call No.2 - ' + data.data);
}, function (err) {
    console.log('error on batch call No.2 (This is expected - just to illustrate an error in one of the batched requests) - ' + angular.fromJson(err));
});
```

La petición enviada a servidor es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En GitHub también se incluye [este proyecto](https://github.com/jonsamwell/angular-http-batcher/tree/master/servers/WebApi2) que implementa el servidor OData usando Web API 2 en el que se puede ver como se configura la ruta que acepta las peticiones batch de OData:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "BatchApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/batch",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: null,
    handler: new DefaultHttpBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
```

Answer (score 0):

**¿Por qué no puedo POST(ear) colecciones desde AngularJS a Odata?**

Esto es una limitación del propio `Odata`, ya existe una [petición](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/135) para que se implemente.

**¿Cómo puedo POST(ear) colecciones desde AngularJS a Odata?**

Para resolver la problemática propongo 2 cosas:

**1. Hacer `batching` de las Entidades y enviarlas 1 a 1.**

En lugar de generar tu petición con un `Enumerable` crea una función que reciba las entidades una a una. En lugar de hacer un `POST` para todas las entidades se hace un `POST` por cada entidad.

En tu caso:

**Controlador**

```
public class EntidadesController : ODataController
    {
       public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Entidad entidad)
         {

            // TODO: Add create logic here.
            var x = entidad;

            //ACTUALIZA BASE DE DATOS BLA BLA BLA
            ...
```

**2. Obtener entidades con Query**

Sólo si es *posible* que tu función `procesaEntidades()` sea replicable a una Query de las Entidades podrías pasar sólo los parámetros necesarios para hacer la Query a la controladora y dentro de ésta obtener todas las entidades a la vez.

Es decir, eliminar al completo el envío/procesado de las Entidades en el POST y sustituirlo por la lógica de tu función `procesaEntidades()`:

**AngularJS**

```
...
//entidades = [];
//entidades = procesaEntidades();

$http.post('http://blabla/entidades',JSON.stringify(logicaQuery))
.then(function(){alert('ok')},function(err){alert('error');});
```

**Controlador**

```
public class EntidadesController : ODataController
    {
       public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(String logicaQuery)
         {


            //Realizar una Wuery sobre las entidades (Con Linq)
            ...
```

---

También destacar que en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486789/post-ienumerable-1000s-of-records) del SO original hicieron un workaround interesante con `Query`.

Comment: PSI El enlace a la peticion esta mal. Apunta a otro issue no relacionado y que esta cerrado y completo.

Comment: Hola, lo que se está buscando es como actualizar varias entidades en una única petición, usando el soporte para [procesado por lotes](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/batch-processing/) de ODATA. De esta manera, supuestamente, la actualización de las entidades se realizaría en la misma transacción de base de datos

Answer (score 0):

no deberias usar una peticion post si no mas bien patch, ya que quieres enviar un conjunto, post es 1 a 1, patch es un conjunto, deberias entender primero que es odata y una API REST FULL, lee esta tabla y analiza bien el tema de tu api.

**http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html**

ademas, te dejo el link donde alguien ya pregunto como realizar una peticion patch con angularjs

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000176/patch-request-using-angularjs**

Comment: Hola, OData solo admite peticiones [patch](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/#differentialupdat) sobre una única entidad, para actualizar varias entidades de golpe hay que realizar una petición batch, lo explico un poco mejor en [mi respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/17695/602). Saludos

Comment: si sabes eso, porque pones como ejemplo realizar una petición del tipo post?

Comment: Si te refieres al ejemplo que hay en la pregunta, es del autor original. En un principio es lo que pretendía hacer y si lees en los comentarios, el propio autor se dio cuenta de que la solución era una petición BATCH. Realmente, la petición BATCH es de tipo POST y en teoría puede incluir peticiones de todo tipo **GET**, **POST**, **PUT** e incluso **PATCH** A mi me pareció interesante porque me estoy planteando usar OData, y al final he llegado a la solución que he compartido. Saludos